# Material UI Select button label appearing above component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use the Material UI select component with FormControl and InputLabel, the the label of the select always renders above the select component and I cannot figure out why.

my code looks something like this

```
 <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="hey">A Label</InputLabel>
      <Select inputProps={{
         id: "hey"
      }} value="Hey">
          <MenuItem value="Hey">
             Hey
          </MenuItem>
      </Select>
   </FormControl>
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? That is also where the label appears in the [Material UI demos](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/).

Comment: @RyanCogswell in the demos the label sits in the Select box then moves up when the Select box is clicked. At least it does on Google Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The label will only sit **in** the Select box if the currently selected option has an empty value; otherwise it needs to show the selected item instead and the label has to be up out of the way. In your example, you only have a single option in your Select with a value of "Hey" so that will start out selected and that will be shown.

Here's an example showing side-by-side your sample `Select` and one that starts with an empty value selected:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  }
});

function App({ classes }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="hey">A Label</InputLabel>
        <Select
          inputProps={{
            id: "hey"
          }}
          value="Hey"
        >
          <MenuItem value="Hey">Hey</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="hey2">A Label</InputLabel>
        <Select
          inputProps={{
            id: "hey2"
          }}
          value={value}
          onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">Empty Value for First Option</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Hey">Hey</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Labelled Select]

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when using material-ui `v3.9.2`. I updated to the latest version (currently `v4.5.0`) and that fixed it for me.