# MaterialUI Label misplacement on Select component

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, label

I have a form displaying inside a modal component with several text inputs and select components but somehow the Select Labels are showing at the top left corner of the form. I followed the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964905/material-ui-select-button-label-appearing-above-component) but I am obtaining the same result. Another problem is that when clicking on one Select the other seems to be linked and show focused. I am not experienced with Material and I have been using it for a couple of days only. I really like it but I am a bit lost here. Also, the Select on the left is not aligned with the Text input.

This is the Dialog/Form code. Disregard the Select onChange event functions

```
            {/* Modal Dialog to add the Form*/} 
        
            <Dialog maxWidth="100" open={createOpportunity} onClose={handleDialogClose}>
                <DialogTitle align='center' id="form-dialog-title">Add New Opportunity</DialogTitle>
                <FormControl className={classes.formMainClass}>
                    <div className='formDivs'> 
                        <TextField autoFocus margin="dense" id="name" label="Opportunity Name" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <TextField margin="dense" id="address" label="Address" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <TextField margin="dense" id="city" label="City" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <div className='state-zip'>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="state">State</InputLabel>
                            <Select fullWidth inputProps={{id: "state"}} value={value} onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}>
                               <MenuItem value="">Empty Value for First Option</MenuItem>
                               <MenuItem value="Hey">Hey</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                            <span> </span>
                            <TextField margin="dense" id="zip" label="Zip" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        </div>
                        <TextField margin="dense" id="architect" label="Architect" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <TextField margin="dense" id="consultant" label="Consultant" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <TextField margin="dense" id="duedate" label="Due date" type="date" fullWidth InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='formDivs'>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="manager">Manager</InputLabel>
                        <Select fullWidth inputProps={{id: "manager"}} value={value} onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}>

                        </Select>
                        <div className='state-zip'>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="status">Status</InputLabel>
                            <Select fullWidth inputProps={{id: "status"}} value={value} onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}>

                            </Select>
                            <span> </span>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="source">Source</InputLabel>
                            <Select fullWidth inputProps={{id: "source"}} value={value} onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}>

                            </Select>
                        </div>
                        <TextField multiline rows={4} rowsMax={Infinity} margin="dense" id="description" label="Description" type="text" fullWidth/>
                        <TextField multiline rows={4} rowsMax={Infinity} margin="dense" id="notes" label="Notes" type="text" fullWidth/>
                    </div>
                </FormControl>
                <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>Opportunities text.</DialogContentText>
                    
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleDialogClose} color="primary">Cancel</Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleDialogClose} color="primary">Save</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
```

Code for the Styling

```
.opportunities {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
}

.top-buttons {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
}

.formDivs {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1% 3%;
}

.state-zip, .manager {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

[image]

Any advise, comment or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: SandBox link below: Refresh the page for dependency errors

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pine-xshq9?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is happening because you're using the `FormControl` element in the wrong way. This element is used to get extra control/feature/functionality over the individual form input.
So wrap your input elements with `FormControl` individually if you're planning to use `FormControl` functionalities and use `div` or `form` as a wrapping element instead of `FormControl` in your current code(`form` will be better).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188214/what-is-formcontrol-used-for-why-is-it-used-how-should-it-be-used) is a related answer

Here is a working demo with the `form` tag :
[image: Edit crazy-shape-0gzzd]

Comment: Thank you @Rajiv. Now I know what is FormControl used for.

Comment: Do you know why the Label text does not fall inside the Select component?

Comment: wrap the `Select` and `InputLabel` element with `FormControl`. for reference check the 'manager' and  'state' select inputs in the demo.